# Four-vector formulation of electromagnetic quantities

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

The following question relates to Page 48 of Herr's [Short Overview of Special Relativity and Invariant Formulation of Electrodynamics](https://cds.cern.ch/record/2674125/files/337.pdf). In the section concerning electromagnetic quantities, we define the 4-current $J^\mu = (\rho \cdot c, \vec{j})$ and attempt to establish some of its basic properties. In particular, it is stated in the text that: *Since scalar products of four-vectors are invariant, one writes*

$$\partial_\mu J^\mu = 0.$$

The invariance of the scalar products of four-vectors across different reference frames is well-understood, but I am unsure as to why this implies that the RHS of the above equation must be zero. Any help in understanding this would be much appreciated.

Comment: That is a very confusing way of putting it. All the invariance tells you is that the right hand side has to be a scalar. To show it’s zero, you need to use something else.

Comment: This was my confusion when reading it.

Answer (score 0):

It follows from Maxwell's equations. See charge [conservation equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_conservation)

In [covariant formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_formulation_of_classical_electromagnetism)

$$
\partial_\nu F^{\mu\nu}=J^\mu
$$

Where $F$ is the electromagnetic tensor

So

$$
\partial_\mu J^\mu=\partial_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}=-\partial_{\mu\nu}F^{\nu\mu}=-\partial_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}=0
$$

Since $F^{\mu\nu}=-F^{\nu\mu}$, i.e. the electromagnetic tensor is anti-symmetric with respect to index exchange, whereas partial derivative is symmetric